# Faker on Laravel 5.5 don't add values to databse

Tags: laravel, faker, mysql-error-1364

I don't know what is the problem with faker but it refused to add new rows in the database and show the message:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'title' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into 'categories' ('updated_at', 'created_at') values (2017-09-14 16:17:43, 2017-09-14 16:17:43))
```

while the code for the factory is this:

```
$factory->define(App\Category::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence(4),
        'description' => $faker->text(300),
    ];
});
```

Is anyone else facing the same problem or i am the only one in the planet :P

Comment: I was searching for a way to use methods globally and i realised that with `use  ClassName` i could use all the class methods inside the actual model. This technique prevent my model from working properly. My model was like:
     `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Category extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ["title", "description"];
    use GeneralMethods;


    public function posts()`

By removing the `use GeneralMethods;` fix my problem

Answer (score 1):

The most possible reason for the null value is, that your values aren't fillable.
You Category Class should have a variable like:

```
protected $fillable = ["title", "description"];
```

detailed example: http://kaloraat.com/articles/generate-fake-data-using-faker-and-factory-in-laravel

Comment: even with the `$fillable` variable it shows again the same error